# OS X app to backup some local folders to a remote server using SFTP, SCP (SSH based)?

Tags: macos

I have tryed many scripted ways to do this (embedded scripts in my IDE) but it is not a reliable way to do it.

Do you know mac OS applications permitting to backup (incrementaly ?) selected folders to a remote server using SSH, SCP, SFTP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link: http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/rsync_time_machine.html

How to make a TimeMachine with the above mentioned rsync command.

*Add the -E paramater, and @Ned told. And be sure than you're not using an GNU version, for example from the macports. To ensure this, always use the full pathname to original Apple's rsync: /usr/bin/rsync.*

Answer (score 0):

Try rsync, it's built in and runs over the SSH network protocol. Only gotcha is that it has to be installed on the remote server as well, but most Unix machines have this out of the box too.

```
rsync -Avz local-dir me@remote-box:remote-dir
```

Comment: Be careful about backing up extended attributes (includes resource forks) from OS X files; some Mac applications depend on them and, if you are not careful, you'll end up with useless copies.  The Apple-supplied `/usr/bin/rsync` in recent OS X versions will transfer extended attributes with `-E`.  For other `rsyncs`s, `-E` means something different.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out http://www.immortalfiles.com. 
This is exact the type of application you need. Incremental backup to remote server. Even all file attributes are saved correctly. I quite surprised that this application is not widely known.